# Applying a class to a array item which is not in the original array using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array which displays data as mat-select dropdown. The user can select any tags he wants. Also we have some free form text field inside the dropdown of tags from which the user can create his own custom text apart from tags array. See below:

**display.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <mat-label class="full-width">Select Tag</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="tagsControl" [(ngModel)]="project.tags" multiple>

    <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let tagging of firstFormGroup.value.tagsControl" [removable]="true"
                  (removed)="onTaggingRemoved(tagging)">
          {{ tagging }}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let tagging of tagsList"
                [value]="tagging">{{tagging}}</mat-option>

    <mat-form-field style="margin-left: 17px; margin-top: 8px;">
      <input matInput placeholder="Add New Tag" #input>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" style="margin-left: 4px;" class="common-button"
            (click)="addNewTags(input.value)">
      Add</button>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**display.component.ts**

```
onTaggingRemoved(tagging: string){
  const taggings = this.firstFormGroup.value.tagsControl as string[];
  this.removeFirst(taggings, tagging);
  this.firstFormGroup.controls['tagsControl'].patchValue(taggings);
}

removeFirst<T>(array: T[], toRemove: T): void {
  const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

addNewTags(value: string) {
  this.tagsList.push(value);
}
```

**table.component.ts**

```
tags: string[] = ["Prod", "Stg", "Dev", "QA"];
```

**table.component.html**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="tags">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    Tags </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
    <span *ngIf="element.tags && element.tags.length < 35" matTooltipPosition="above"
          matTooltip="{{element.tags}}">
        
      <span *ngIf="element.tags == 'Prod'">
        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-info font-color-tags">{{ element.tags.join(', ') }}</span>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="element.tags == 'Stg'">
        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-primary font-color-tags">{{ element.tags.join(', ')}}</span>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="element.tags == 'Dev'">
        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-secondary font-color-tags">{{ element.tags.join(', ')}}</span>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="element.tags == 'QA'">
        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-success font-color-tags">{{ element.tags.join(', ')}}</span>
      </span>                      
         
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="element.tags.length == 0">
      -
    </span>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

My question is i am adding the badges the color codes to different array items based in its value. I mean if the tags array item value is "QA", i am adding different color, similarly for "Prod" different color. But i need to add some custom badge color to the custom tag which user created on his own other than tags array. I am planning to add a unique badge to all custom color badge then how to achieve this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sur I got your question but if I did, you want to apply to any new tag in the four you have the correct badge.

In this way, your html code have to be dynamic with [ngClass] like :

```
<span [ngClass]="method_to_return_badge(element.tags)">{{ element.tags.join(', ')}}</span>
```

You then have to define the method_to_return_badge in your ts and with a switch on the four possibilities return the right badge.

This will let you write less code in your html and make it more readable.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Actually i have pre-defined colors for 4 array items but if the user creates his own tag then i have to give a color say some red. This is what i want to achieve.

Comment: You can use this solution for any new tag, just associate it with a new badge. To do it dynamically, you can persist you array items with the corresponding badge when it's create as a map. And then you just need to get you data from your db. You just have to make sur the new badge you crate for the custom tag is not already associate.